# Как получить значения переменной в промисе без использования console.log

Tags: javascript

Результат операции 2+2 в переменной a, можно получить через

```
var a = 2 + 2; 
console.log(a);
```

а можно просто обращаться к переменной "a", без использования console.log

```
var a = 2 + 2; 
a;
```

Нижеприведенный скрипт работает и выводит результат (4 и 5), только благодаря команде "console.log(foo)" см.ниже

```js
function f1() 
{ 
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        var foo = 2 + 2;
        resolve(console.log(foo)); 
    })
}

function f2() 
{ 
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        var foo = 2 + 3;
        resolve(console.log(foo)); 
    })
}
f1()
.then(a => {return a;})
.then(f2)
.then(a => {return a;});
```

если убрать эту команду то скрипт уже не выводит результат, почему так? и как сделать чтобы работало и без этой команды

```js
function f1() 
{ 
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        var foo = 2 + 2;
        resolve(foo); 
    })
}

function f2() 
{ 
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        var foo = 2 + 3;
        resolve(foo); 
    })
}
f1()
.then(a => {return a;})
.then(f2)
.then(a => {return a;});
```

Comment: вы хотите без использования console.log выводить что-то в консоль, или использовать результат промиса в другом месте кода?

Comment: Что простите? Что именно вам надо сделать со значением? Если нужен вывод, то только через `console.log`, `alert` и вставка в DOM. Если хотите просто посмотреть на значение, то вам надо прописать `debugger;` перед нужной строчкой, но при этом консоль разработчика должна быть открыта

Answer (score -1):

У вас просто используется return, который возвращает значение, но не отображает. Если принципиально не хочется использовать console.log() - есть прекрасный console.dir();

Однако, можно попробовать просто вписать этот код в консоль браузера и тогда это вполне может отображаться в консоли без лишних обращений в методу отображения.